# How to copy a 2D array (matrix) from python with a C function (and do some computer heavy computation) which return a 2D array (matrix) in python?

Tags: python, arrays, c, numpy, pointers

I want to copy a 2D numpy array (matrix) in a C function a get it back in python (and then do some calculation on it in C taking the speed advantage of C) . Therefore I need the C function `matrix_copy` to return a 2D array (or, I guess, a pointer to it). I tried with the following code but I get the following output (where one can see the second dimension of the array is lost).

```
matrix_in.shape:
(300, 200)
matrix_out.shape:
(300,)
```

How could I change the code (I guess the `matrix_copy.c` adding some pointer magic) so I could obtain an exact copy of the `matrix_in` in `matrix_out`?

Here is the `main.py` script:

```
from ctypes import c_void_p, c_double, c_int, cdll
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np
import pdb

n = 300
m = 200
matrix_in = np.random.randn(n, m)

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("matrix_copy.so")
matrix_copy = lib.matrix_copy
matrix_copy.restype = ndpointer(dtype=c_double,
                          shape=(n,))

matrix_out = matrix_copy(c_void_p(matrix_in.ctypes.data),
            c_int(n),
            c_int(m))

print("matrix_in.shape:")
print(matrix_in.shape)
print("matrix_out.shape:")
print(matrix_out.shape)
```

Here is the `matrix_copy.c` script:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double * matrix_copy(const double * matrix_in, int n, int m){
    double * matrix_out = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * (n*m));
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            matrix_out[i+j] = matrix_in[i+j];
            //matrix_out[i][j] = matrix_in[i][j];
            // some heavy computations not yet implemented
        }
    }
    return matrix_out;
}
```

which I compile with the command

```
cc -fPIC -shared -o matrix_copy.so matrix_copy.c
```

And as a side note, why does the notation `matrix_out[i][j] = matrix_in[i][j];` throws me an error on compilation?

```
matrix_copy.c:10:26: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
            matrix_out[i][j] = matrix_in[i][j];
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
matrix_copy.c:10:44: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
            matrix_out[i][j] = matrix_in[i][j];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second dimension is 'lost' because you explicitly omit it in the named `shape` argument of `ndpointer`. Change:

```py
matrix_copy.restype = ndpointer(dtype=c_double, shape=(n,))
```

to

```py
matrix_copy.restype = ndpointer(dtype=c_double, shape=(n,m), flags='C')
```

Where [`flags='C'`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer) additionally notes that the returned data is stored *contiguously* in *row major order*.

---

With regards to `matrix_out[i][j] = matrix_in[i][j];` throwing an error, consider that `matrix_in` is of type `const double *`. `matrix_in[i]` would yield a value of type `const double` - how do you further index this value (i.e., with `[j]`)?

If you want to emulate accessing a 2-dimensional array via a single pointer, you must calculate offsets manually. `matrix_out[i+j]` is not sufficient, as you must account for the span of each sub array:

```
matrix_out[i * m + j] = matrix_in[i * m + j];
```

---

Note that in C, [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is the generally preferred type to use when dealing with memory sizes or array lengths.

`matrix_copy.c`, simplified:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double *matrix_copy(const double *matrix_in, size_t n, size_t m)
{
    double *matrix_out = malloc(sizeof *matrix_out * n * m);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++)
            matrix_out[i * m + j] = matrix_in[i * m + j];

    return matrix_out;
}
```

`matrix.py`, with more explicit typing:

```py
from ctypes import c_void_p, c_double, c_size_t, cdll, POINTER
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np

c_double_p = POINTER(c_double)

n = 300
m = 200
matrix_in = np.random.randn(n, m).astype(c_double)

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("matrix_copy.so")
matrix_copy = lib.matrix_copy
matrix_copy.argtypes = c_double_p, c_size_t, c_size_t
matrix_copy.restype = ndpointer(
        dtype=c_double,
        shape=(n,m),
        flags='C')

matrix_out = matrix_copy(
        matrix_in.ctypes.data_as(c_double_p),
        c_size_t(n),
        c_size_t(m))

print("matrix_in.shape:", matrix_in.shape)
print("matrix_out.shape:", matrix_out.shape)
print("in == out", matrix_in == matrix_out)
```

Comment: Many thanks @Oka. Brilliant answer! Lot to digest... ;). So would there be a solution with the notation `matrix_out[i][j]`? and additionally, do you have a good reference to understand the verbose `matrix_copy.restype = ndpointer(dtype=c_double, shape=(n,m), flags='C')`?

Comment: Numpy documentation for [`ndpointer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer). [*Row- and column-major order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) for the difference between C and Fortran memory layouts. A solution with `matrix_out[i][j]` notation would require the C function argument to be of type `double **` (*pointer-to-pointer-to-double*), or `double (*)[m]` (*pointer-to-array-of-size-m*), or equivalent. See: [*Pass 2D array*](https://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html).

Comment: many thanks again for your very good answer which I am still learning from a lot. If you want, I have posted anoter similar question about how to write a C function taking 2 different matrices as argument which I posted there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73806188/how-to-write-a-function-in-c-which-takes-as-input-two-matrices-as-numpy-array

Comment: Dear @Oka. I ran into new trouble with the code and the matrix notation in C. I posted a new question there in case you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74171783/boundary-problems-using-a-numpy-kernel-and-padding-on-a-matrix-within-a-c-functi?noredirect=1#comment130955162_74171783

Answer (score 0):

The incoming data is a probably single block of memory. You need to create the substructure.

In my C++ code I have to do the following on data (block) coming in via swig:

```
void divide2DDoubleArray(double * &block, double ** &subblockdividers, int noofsubblocks, int subblocksize){
    /* The starting address of a block of doubles is used to generate
     * pointers to subblocks.
     *
     *      block: memory containing the original block of data
     *      subblockdividers: array of subblock addresses
     *      noofsubblocks: specify the number of subblocks produced
     *      subblocksize: specify the size of the subblocks produced
     *
     * Design by contract: application should make sure the memory
     * in block is allocated and initialized properly.
     */
    // Build 2D matrix for cols
    subblockdividers=new double *[noofsubblocks];
    subblockdividers[0]= block;
    for (int i=1; i<noofsubblocks; ++i) {
        subblockdividers[i] = &subblockdividers[i-1][subblocksize];
    }
}
```

Now the pointer returned in subblockdividers can be used the way you would like to.

Don't forget to free subblockdividers when your done. (Note: adjustments might be needed to compile this as C code)