# How to write a function in C which takes as input two matrices as numpy array

Tags: python, c, numpy, matrix, malloc

I want to implement a function in C which takes as input two matrices as numpy array and return another matrix.

First I have the function in C in the file `f_2_mat_in.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double *f_2_mat_in(
    const double *matrix_one, 
    size_t n, 
    size_t m,
    const double *matrix_two,
    size_t u, 
    size_t v
    )
{
  double *matrix_out = malloc(sizeof *matrix_out * n * m);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < m; j++){
      printf("%f ", matrix_one[i * m + j]);
      matrix_out[i * m + j] = matrix_one[i * m + j];
    printf("--\n");
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < u; i++){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < v; j++){
      printf("%f ", matrix_two[u * v + j]);
    printf("--\n");
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
  return matrix_out;
}
```

Then I have the `main.py` python script which uses`f_2_mat_in`: c

```
from ctypes import c_void_p, c_double, c_size_t, c_int, cdll, POINTER
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import pdb
import numpy as np

c_double_p1 = POINTER(c_double)
c_double_p2 = POINTER(c_double)

n = 5 
m = 4
kernel_size = 3
u = 3 
v = 6
matrix_one = np.random.randn(n, m).astype(c_double)
matrix_one[0][1] = np.nan
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("f_2_mat_in.so")
f_2_mat_in = lib.f_2_mat_in
f_2_mat_in.argtypes = c_int, c_double_p1, c_size_t, c_size_t, c_double_p2, c_size_t, c_size_t
f_2_mat_in.restype = ndpointer(
        dtype=c_double,
        shape=(n,m),
        flags='C')
f_2_mat_in.restype = ndpointer(
        dtype=c_double,
        shape=(u,v),
        flags='C')

matrix_out = f_2_mat_in(
        c_int(kernel_size),
        matrix_one.ctypes.data_as(c_double_p1),
        c_size_t(n),
        c_size_t(m),
        matrix_one.ctypes.data_as(c_double_p2),
        c_size_t(u),
        c_size_t(v))

print("matrix_one:", matrix_one)
print("matrix_two:", matrix_two)
print("matrix_out:", matrix_out)
print("matrix_one.shape:", matrix_one.shape)
print("matrix_two.shape:", matrix_two.shape)
print("matrix_out.shape:", matrix_out.shape)
print("in == out", matrix_one == matrix_out)
pdb.set_trace()
```

Finally I have bash script which compile the C script and run the pyhon script:

```
a=f_2_mat_in
cc -fPIC -shared -o $a.so $a.c && python main.py
```

I get the following error (in MacOS `11.6.1`):

```
Python(53609,0x111c84e00) malloc: can't allocate region
:*** mach_vm_map(size=5626830804037632, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
Python(53609,0x111c84e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for common mistakes (regarding ***argtypes***, ***restype***) when working with *CTypes*.
But since working with *NumPy* arrays, things can be refined even more according to [[NumPy]: C-Types Foreign Function Interface (numpy.ctypeslib)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#c-types-foreign-function-interface-numpy-ctypeslib).

Original code has problems:

- *C*:

  - Indexes going outside bounds inside 2<sup>nd</sup> loop (***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*)
  - Matrix not being freed (memory leak)
- *Python*:

  - *argtypes* and *restype* not being properly set

    - Function header not matching *C*
  - 2<sup>nd</sup> matrix not being defined
  - Many more

  So I decided to start it from scratch.

I assume (as I didn't run the original code) the *malloc* error is because it tried to dereference the 1<sup>st</sup> argument that *Python*' passed an *int*, while *C* interpreted it as a *double** - which is (again) ***UB***.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif

#define ELEMENT_TYPE double

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API ELEMENT_TYPE* matrixFunc(const ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat0, size_t rows0, size_t cols0, const ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat1, size_t rows1, size_t cols1);
DLL00_EXPORT_API void deallocArray(ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


ELEMENT_TYPE* matrixFunc(
    const ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat0,
    size_t rows0,
    size_t cols0,
    const ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat1,
    size_t rows1,
    size_t cols1)
{
    size_t matSize = sizeof(ELEMENT_TYPE) * cols0 * rows0;
    ELEMENT_TYPE *pRet = (ELEMENT_TYPE*)(malloc(matSize));

    printf("\nC: - 1st matrix (%zu, %zu):\n", rows0, cols0);
    memcpy(pRet, pMat0, matSize);  // Faster than setting each element individually
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows0; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols0; ++j) {
            printf("%3.3f ", pMat0[i * cols0 + j]);
            //pRet[i * cols0 + j] = pMat0[i * cols0 + j];
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nC: - 2nd matrix (%zu, %zu):\n", rows1, cols1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows1; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols1; ++j) {
            printf("%3.3f ", pMat1[i * cols1 + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    return pRet;
}


void deallocArray(ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat)
{
    if (pMat)
        free(pMat);
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import sys

import numpy as np


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


def np_mat_type(rows, cols, element_type=float):
    return np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=element_type, shape=(rows, cols), flags="C_CONTIGUOUS")


def main(*argv):
    np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
    rows0 = 5
    cols0 = 4
    kernel_size = 3
    rows1 = 3
    cols1 = 6
    mat0 = np.random.randn(rows0, cols0).astype(cts.c_double)
    mat1 = np.random.randn(rows1, cols1).astype(cts.c_double)

    dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    matrix_func = dll.matrixFunc
    matrix_func.argtypes = (
        np_mat_type(rows0, cols0), cts.c_size_t, cts.c_size_t,
        np_mat_type(rows1, cols1), cts.c_size_t, cts.c_size_t)
    matrix_func.restype = np_mat_type(rows0, cols0)

    dealloc_array = dll.deallocArray
    dealloc_array.argtypes = (np_mat_type(rows0, cols0),)
    dealloc_array.restype = None

    print("mat0:")
    print(mat0)
    print("\nmat1:")
    print(mat1)
    mat_res = matrix_func(mat0, rows0, cols0, mat1, rows1, cols1)
    print("result:")
    print(mat_res)
    print("\nequality:", np.all(mat_res == mat0))

    dealloc_array(mat_res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

- *Nix* (*Linux*):

  > ```
  > (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q073806188]> ~/sopr.sh
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [064bit prompt]> ls
  > code00.py  dll00.c
  > [064bit prompt]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o dll00.so dll00.c
  > [064bit prompt]> ls
  > code00.py  dll00.c  dll00.so
  > [064bit prompt]>
  > [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py
  > Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
  >
  > mat0:
  > [[-0.83  -0.892 -1.137  0.333]
  >  [-0.608 -1.403 -0.74   0.652]
  >  [-0.299 -1.987 -1.009 -0.35 ]
  >  [-0.383  1.173  0.772 -0.616]
  >  [-1.063 -0.33   0.124 -0.639]]
  >
  > mat1:
  > [[ 0.017  0.207  0.051  0.269  0.131  0.282]
  >  [ 0.911  0.686  0.491 -1.846 -2.196  0.287]
  >  [ 1.897 -0.174  2.99  -0.104 -0.376 -0.404]]
  >
  > C: - 1st matrix (5, 4):
  > -0.830 -0.892 -1.137 0.333
  > -0.608 -1.403 -0.740 0.652
  > -0.299 -1.987 -1.009 -0.350
  > -0.383 1.173 0.772 -0.616
  > -1.063 -0.330 0.124 -0.639
  >
  > C: - 2nd matrix (3, 6):
  > 0.017 0.207 0.051 0.269 0.131 0.282
  > 0.911 0.686 0.491 -1.846 -2.196 0.287
  > 1.897 -0.174 2.990 -0.104 -0.376 -0.404
  >
  > result:
  > [[-0.83  -0.892 -1.137  0.333]
  >  [-0.608 -1.403 -0.74   0.652]
  >  [-0.299 -1.987 -1.009 -0.35 ]
  >  [-0.383  1.173  0.772 -0.616]
  >  [-1.063 -0.33   0.124 -0.639]]
  >
  > equality: True
  >
  > Done.
  > ```
- *Win*:

  > ```
  > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073806188]> sopr.bat
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
  >
  > [prompt]> dir /b
  > code00.py
  > dll00.c
  > dll00.so
  >
  > [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
  > dll00.c
  >    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
  >
  > [prompt]> dir /b
  > code00.py
  > dll00.c
  > dll00.dll
  > dll00.exp
  > dll00.lib
  > dll00.obj
  > dll00.so
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
  > Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
  >
  > mat0:
  > [[-0.883  1.441 -1.563  1.452]
  >  [-1.751 -0.625 -0.782 -0.326]
  >  [-0.257 -0.838 -0.356 -0.187]
  >  [ 0.503  0.981  0.041  0.383]
  >  [-0.637 -1.098  0.122  1.086]]
  >
  > mat1:
  > [[ 1.139  1.059  0.621  1.128  0.872 -0.163]
  >  [-0.159  0.15   0.163  1.379  0.486  0.349]
  >  [ 0.855  0.447 -1.12   0.257 -0.22   0.099]]
  >
  > C: - 1st matrix (5, 4):
  > -0.883 1.441 -1.563 1.452
  > -1.751 -0.625 -0.782 -0.326
  > -0.257 -0.838 -0.356 -0.187
  > 0.503 0.981 0.041 0.383
  > -0.637 -1.098 0.122 1.086
  >
  > C: - 2nd matrix (3, 6):
  > 1.139 1.059 0.621 1.128 0.872 -0.163
  > -0.159 0.150 0.163 1.379 0.486 0.349
  > 0.855 0.447 -1.120 0.257 -0.220 0.099
  >
  > result:
  > [[-0.883  1.441 -1.563  1.452]
  >  [-1.751 -0.625 -0.782 -0.326]
  >  [-0.257 -0.838 -0.356 -0.187]
  >  [ 0.503  0.981  0.041  0.383]
  >  [-0.637 -1.098  0.122  1.086]]
  >
  > equality: True
  >
  > Done.
  > ```

Comment: Many thanks for this elegant and comprehensive answer @CristiFati. Would it be possible to explain a few points: 

Point #1: With respect to the following expression
```DLL00_EXPORT_API ELEMENT_TYPE* matrixFunc(const ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat0, size_t rows0, size_t cols0, const ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat1, size_t rows1, size_t cols1);
DLL00_EXPORT_API void deallocArray(ELEMENT_TYPE *pMat);
```
why is `DLL00_EXPORT_API` necessary. I it commented out `DLL00_EXPORT_API` and it works fine on my machine (MacOS `11.6.1`)

Comment: Point #2: the deallocation function in the C code. Can you explain why you wrote the following: 
```if (pMat)
     free(pMat);
```
and why do you deallocate only mat_res and mat0 and mat1.

Point #3: could you explain what the following expression does?
```rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: 1. *ELEMENT\_TYPE* is a define to *double* (to be easy to modify (in one place) in the future). *DLL00\_EXPORT\_API* is for windows only (`#if defined(_WIN32)`) (the code runs on both *Nix* and *Win*), 2. to only free the pointer if it's not *NULL* (although it's not necessary as the check is also performed in *free*), 3. check https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv - strips the 1st arg (script name) and unpacks them (I have a standard *.py* file "template" that contains that stuff, you can remove it).

Comment: Dear @CristiFati. Thanks a lot for your answer again. I ran into new trouble with the code and the matrix notation in C. I posted a new question there in case you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74171783/boundary-problems-using-a-numpy-kernel-and-padding-on-a-matrix-within-a-c-functi