# Faster c_double_array. so close

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ctypes

I have a numpy array that I need to get to a `dll` function wrapped in `ctypes`.

```
myFunc.argtypes = (...POINTER(ctypes.c_double),POINTER(ctypes.c_double),...)
myFunc(...Data1_arr,Data2_arr...)
```

I'm defining arrays like this and it works great. its just slow. 1.5ms for a small set of data

```
#these are c_double_array types
Data1_arr = (ctypes.c_double * len(Data1))(*Data1)
Data2_arr = (ctypes.c_double * len(Data2))(*Data2)
```

I found several ways to operate on the numpy arrays more directly, which are much faster. average 6.899999999809836e-06 seconds

```
#these are .LP_c_double types
Data1_ptr = Data1.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
Data2_ptr = Data2.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
```

The Data1_ptr._arr values match the Data1_arr values obviously.

`MyFunc()` even happily takes the `Data1_ptr` and `Data2_ptr` values. However, the output of the function is all messed up.  MyFunc is obviously interpreting the c_double_array correctly, but not the LP_c_double.

I'll admit I'm punching over my weight here, but I am trying to learn.

Is there a way to get the c_double_array from the LP_c_double pointer without wasting extra time?

edit to add this:
here is the C header

```
Proc_WriteData
(
   int32        DataLength,
   const double Data1[],
   const double Data2[]
);
```

Python calling it:

```
def Write_New_Data(Data1,Data2):

    dll.Proc_WriteData.argtypes = (int32,POINTER(ctypes.c_double),POINTER(ctypes.c_double))

    Data_Length = len(Data1)
    Data1_ptr = Data1.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
    Data2_ptr = Data2.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))

    dll.Proc_WriteData(Data_Length, Data1_ptr, Data2_ptr)
```

I did see something like this.  I tried it, but the output of the function was identical to the above.

```
return np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=element_type, shape=(dim,), flags="F_CONTIGUOUS")
```

Im now wondering about `const double`  im wondering if thats where im getting stuck?

Please let me know if you need any more information.
thanks

Comment: Show the *C* function header. and the *Python* code calling it (**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**). [\[SO\]: How to run a Fortran script with ctypes? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75944691/4788546), [\[SO\]: Sending numpy array (image) to c++ library with ctypes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73926710/4788546).

Comment: updated with new information. not sure how SO notifications work, so adding a comment here.

Comment: It's still not clear what the problem is. Is there an error message? Is the .dll written in *Fortran*? There is no *MCVE* here.

Comment: dll is vendor provided. Data gets put out on hardware. Signal coming out is not correct.   Using Data1_arr = (ctypes.c_double * len(Data1))(*Data1), i get the correct output.  Using 'Data1_ptr = Data1.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))', i get the incorrect output.  No errors, just incorrect output.  At the end of the day, i would love to be able to access the data @.LP_c_double and pass it in just like the c_double_array.  Im very green at this, so im sorry if thats a stupid question.   Seems like the c_double_array is creating a copy of data array vs id love to just pass by ref?

Comment: Also, i would love to include sample of (non)-working code, but cant include dll.  is there a way to use a fake dll for demo purposes?  again, im very green.

Comment: Well, i figured this out yesterday.  This (Data1_arr = (ctypes.c_double * len(Data1))(*Data1)) is creating floats, which evidently, the hardware likes. So, i made sure the the data is type float prior to calling this(Data1_ptr = Data1.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))).  and then everything worked as expected and much faster.  I appreciate your help guys!