# Passing a numpy array to C function through ctypes gives wrong results if the numpy array is not casted

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

Consider this simple C source code which computes the mean of an array of `int`, stores it in a structure and returns an error code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

enum errors {
    NO_ERRORS,
    EMPTY_ARRAY
};

struct Result {
    double mean;
};

enum errors calculateMean(struct Result *result, int *array, int length) {
    if (length == 0) {
        return EMPTY_ARRAY; // Return EMPTY_ARRAY if the array is empty
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    result->mean = (double)sum / length;

    return NO_ERRORS; // Return NO_ERRORS if calculation is successful
}
```

The code is compiled to a shared library named `libtest_ctypes.so`.

I have the following ctypes interface:

```py
import ctypes
import enum

import numpy as np
import enum

lib_path = "./libtest_ctypes.so" 
lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)

# The Result structure
class Result(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("mean", ctypes.c_double)]

# The Errors enum
class Errors(enum.IntEnum):
    NO_ERRORS = 0
    EMPTY_ARRAY = 1

# Defining a signature for `calculateMean`
calculate_mean = lib.calculateMean
calculate_mean.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(Result), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.c_int]
calculate_mean.restype = Errors


# Runs `calculateMean`
def calculate_mean_interface(array):
    result = Result()
    length = len(array)

    c_array = array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))

    error = calculate_mean(ctypes.byref(result), c_array, length)
    return error, result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

    error, result = calculate_mean_interface(array)

    if error == Errors.EMPTY_ARRAY:
        print("Error: Empty array!")
    elif error == Errors.NO_ERRORS:
        print("Mean:", result.mean)
```

Running the python interface gives a wrong result `1.2`.
To my undestanding this is due to a difference in types between the numpy array (64 bit integeres) and the C's `int` on my machine.
I can get the right result, `3.0`, casting the array to `ctype.c_int` through numpy's `.astype()`:

```py
def calculate_mean_interface(array):
    result = Result()
    length = len(array)

    #** CAST ARRAY TO CTYPES.C_INT**
    array = array.astype(ctypes.c_int)
    c_array = array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))

    error = calculate_mean(ctypes.byref(result), c_array, length)
    return error, result
```

However numpy's casting requires extra memory and time.
What is the best way to achieve a correct result without casting?
I'd like this to be portable and, if possible, I don't want to specify a dtype when initializing the numpy array.

Comment: You have a buffer of 64-byte integers, and a function that needs a buffer of 32-byte integers. You are not going to pass that buffer to that function and have it work. The conversion is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the message. But maybe is there a way to avoid how numpy does it, i.e. by allocating to memory and casting each array element? Maybe using a view and specifying a stride  we can avoid this?

Comment: Views and strides will not turn the buffer you have into the buffer you need. Your C function does not handle strides, just as it does not handle any data type other than `int`.

Comment: I understand, I will change my C code to use fixed length integers and initialize numpy arrays accordingly. if you want to make an answer I'll mark it as correct tomorrow

Comment: I get `np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).dtype == dtype('int32')`.  I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code but it isn't 64-bit integers.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: You're probably on Windows. NumPy's default integer dtype corresponds to C `long`, which is 32-bit on Windows.

Comment: Then specify the dtype explicitly `array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=np.int32)` so it’s in the right format. Can’t really avoid it unless you want to do conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[NumPy]: Scalars - class numpy.int_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.int_) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Signed integer type, compatible with Python *int* and **C *long***.

So, you'll have to use that in all the places (and be consistent), otherwise you'll get ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*.

In your case (***Little Endian* *Nix* *OS*** (and ***Python* build**)), the memory layout is (representation in *HEX* (2 digits per *Byte*)):

```
NumPy array - 5 064bit (long) items: (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 5 = 3.0
╔══════L0══════╗╔══════L1══════╗╔══════L2══════╗╔══════L3══════╗╔══════L4══════╗
10000000000000002000000000000000300000000000000040000000000000005000000000000000
╚══I0══╝╚══I1══╝╚══I2══╝╚══I3══╝╚══I4══╝ ...
C array (same memory) - 5 032bit (int) items: (1 + 0 + 2 + 0 + 3) / 5 = 1.2
```

Check [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546) for more details on integer types.

Here's a working version.

- *dll00.c*:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  typedef enum {
      SUCCESS = 0,
      EMPTY_ARRAY,
      NULL_POINTER,
      UNSPECIFIED,
  } Errors;


  typedef struct {
      double mean;
  } Result;


  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  DLL00_EXPORT_API Errors calculateMean(Result *result, long *array, int length);

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif


  Errors calculateMean(Result *result, long *array, int length)
  {
      printf("From C - element size: %zu\n", sizeof(long));
      if (length == 0) {
          return EMPTY_ARRAY;
      }
      if ((result == NULL) || (array == NULL)) {
          return NULL_POINTER;
      }
      long sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
          sum += array[i];
      }
      result->mean = (double)sum / length;
      return SUCCESS;
  }
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ctypes as cts
  import enum
  import sys

  import numpy as np


  class Result(cts.Structure):
      _fields_ = (
          ("mean", cts.c_double),
      )


  class Errors(enum.IntEnum):
      SUCCESS = 0,
      EMPTY_ARRAY = 1,
      NULL_POINTER = 2,
      UNSPECIFIED = 3,


  DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


  calculate_mean = None  # Initialize it in main


  def calculate_mean_interface(array):
      result = Result()
      length = len(array)

      c_array = array.ctypes.data_as(cts.POINTER(cts.c_long))
      error = calculate_mean(cts.byref(result), c_array, length)
      return error, result


  def main(*argv):

      dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
      global calculate_mean
      calculate_mean = dll.calculateMean
      calculate_mean.argtypes = (cts.POINTER(Result), cts.POINTER(cts.c_long), cts.c_int)
      calculate_mean.restype = Errors


      array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
      print(f"NP array type: {array.dtype}")

      error, result = calculate_mean_interface(array)
      if error != Errors.SUCCESS:
          print(f"Error: {error}")
      else:
          print(f"Mean: {result.mean}")


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Output**:

- *Nix* (*Linux*):

  > ```bash
  > [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q077965251]> . ~/sopr.sh 
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [064bit prompt]> 
  > [064bit prompt]> ls
  > code00.py  dll00.c
  > [064bit prompt]> 
  > [064bit prompt]> gcc -fPIC -shared -o dll00.so dll00.c
  > [064bit prompt]> ls
  > code00.py  dll00.c  dll00.so
  > [064bit prompt]> 
  > [064bit prompt]> /home/cfati/Work/Dev/VEnvs/py_pc064_03.10_test0/bin/python ./code00.py
  > Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux
  >
  > NP array type: int64
  > From C - element size: 8
  > Mean: 3.0
  >
  > Done.
  > ```
- *Win*:

  > ```bat
  > [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q077965251]> sopr.bat
  > ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]>  "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
  >
  > [prompt]> dir /b
  > code00.py
  > dll00.c
  > dll00.so
  >
  > [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
  > dll00.c
  >    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
  >
  > [prompt]> dir /b
  > code00.py
  > dll00.c
  > dll00.dll
  > dll00.exp
  > dll00.lib
  > dll00.obj
  > dll00.so
  >
  > [prompt]>
  > [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
  > Python 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
  >
  > NP array type: int32
  > From C - element size: 4
  > Mean: 3.0
  >
  > Done.
  > ```

Might also want to check:

- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)
- [[SO]: Sending numpy array (image) to c++ library with ctypes (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73926710/4788546)
- [[SO]: Boundary problems using a numpy kernel and padding on a matrix within a C functions called from python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74174207/4788546)
- [[SO]: How to run a Fortran script with ctypes? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75944691/4788546)
- [[SO]: _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517228/4788546)